# MySQL processing large bit fields

Tags: mysql

My goal is to store a 256 bit object (this is actually a bitfield) into MySQL and be able to do some bitwise operations and comparisons to it.

Ideally, I would use BIT(256) for the type but MySQL limits bitfields to 64 bits.

My proposed solution was to use Binary String `BINARY(32)` type for this field and I can store my objects but there is no way I can operate on them.

My table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bin` binary(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

but then the query

```
SELECT 
bit_count( bin ) AS fullBin, 
bit_count( substring( bin, 0, 4 ) ) AS partialBin
FROM test
```

always returns 0 as it does not convert my binary string neither the substring into a number for bit_count to operate on.

I am looking for a way to extract parts of the binary string as `BIGINT` or some other type that I can operate on (I only need bitwise `AND` and `bit_count()` operations).

Performance wise, I would prefer a solution that does not involve creating strings and parsing them.

I would also accept any proposal for storing my data as another type but the obvious solution to split my bin column into 4 ones of type BIT(64) is not an option as I must preserve the table naming structure.

Comment: Why not use 4 `BIGINT`s? What do you mean by "comparison"?

Comment: Please show how you're setting the binary value.

Comment: As I said, i cannot change the table naming structure and replace bin column with bin_0, bin_1... Since data is already stored into `BINARY(32)` if you can provide with a method to extract it into `BIGINT`s you have solved the problem.

Comment: @Zois Why do you need to extract it as `BIGINT`? Shouldn't `TINYINT` be enough to represent a single byte?

Comment: I would prefer to split into 4 `BIGINT` instead of 32 `TINYINT`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams `INSERT INTO test( bin ) VALUES (x'123456789ABCDE')` or `X'123456789ABCDE'` or `0x123456789ABCDE`. Your data must contain even number of digits or it throws an error or is zero padded.